# Estimated Time of Completion given Progress and Elapsed Time

Tags: functions

Say I have some task that I have spent an hour on, and I am 33% done. It should take me 3 hours to complete this task. Another task may be 50% done, and I have spent 3 hours on it. That should take a total of 6 hours. What is that equation?

Something like `time_remaining = f(percent_done, time_spent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```
 time used  =  percent done * total time
```

you want

```
total time = (time used)/(percent done)
```

If you want the remaining time

```
time remaining = total time - time used

               = time used * (1/(percent done) - 1)
```